# In RangeSeek Bar Max and Min Bar Overlapped.How to prevent?

Tags: android, range, seekbar

I have price range seekbar. Need minimum Rs.10 difference will be there in between min and max value.
If min value +10 == maxvalue or maxvalue-10 = minvalue then thumbs(min or max) will not work. In android

Comment: could you show your code?

Comment: Help this
https://github.com/yahoo/android-range-seek-bar/blob/master/rangeseekbar-sample/src/main/java/com/yahoo/mobile/client/android/demo/DemoActivity.java

Comment: RangeSeekBar seekBarInteger;
 seekBarInteger.setOnRangeSeekBarChangeListener(new RangeSeekBar.OnRangeSeekBarChangeListener<Integer>() {

            @Override
            public void onRangeSeekBarValuesChanged(RangeSeekBar<?> bar, Integer minValue, Integer maxValue) {
                Log.e("value", minValue + "  " + maxValue);

                minTextInt.setText("Rs." + minValue);
                maxtextInt.setText("Rs." + maxValue);

                int diff=maxValue-minValue;
                

            }

        });